# busybox ash PS1 not expanding

Tags: shell, prompt, busybox

I am trying to setup busybox's `ash` on an embedded system to support expanding the `PS1` prompt statement. I have it currently set as

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

However, all that is displayed is literally `\u@\h:\w\$`. My environment vars are

- `HOSTNAME=linux`
- `USER=root`
- and my pwd is `/`

So what should be displayed is `root@linux:/$`. Is there something special I need to do to get the `PS1` to expand correctly?

---

One thing I noticed is my `SHELL` variable is `/bin/sh` even though in my `/etc/inittab` I have the following line

```
ttyO0::respawn:-/bin/bash
```

I imagine this is the case because `sh` and `bash` are both aliased to `ash` in the busybox config. However, I have the following options enabled though:

- `bash-compatible extensions`
- `Expand prompt string`

Comment: Did you turn on FEATURE_EDITING (“Command line editing”)? It might help if you posted your Busybox `.config`.

Comment: That fixed the problem. For some reason, finding that was harder than expected. I don't know how long I spent looking in the `menuconfig` and on Google for a solution to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prompt expansion is always enabled in Busybox's ash or hush if it's been compiled in, there is no runtime way of turning it off. Check that it is really compiled in. In particular, in ash, this requires `FEATURE_EDITING` (“Command line editing”) to be enabled as well.